# How to apply css to buttons inside gridview

Tags: asp.net, css, button, gridview

How do I apply CSS to buttons inside a GridView without using CssClass? I have a input
 `["type=submit"]`

in my CSS class and it works for all the buttons except the ones inside the GridView.

I've tried

```
.gvwList input["type=submit"]{}
```

where `gvwList` is the CSS being used by the GridView but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried input[type='submit'] ?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply red_alert but it still doesn't work

Comment: what kind of button it is inside gridview?

Comment: @AndrewLiao can you post rendered grid html output

Comment: @AndrewLiao are you using `asp:ButtonField` or template button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use

```
 .gvwList button{}
```

Check what it is rendering on the browser and make a `css` accordingly.
If it is rendering as `anchor` then you can use

```
  .gvwList a{color: Blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
.gvwList input[type="submit"]
{
   color: red;
}
```

If still not work, you could try also color: red !important;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.gvwList tr td a, .gvwList tr td input[type="submit"]
{
color: Red;
}
```

For

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="save" />
```

try

```
 .gvwList tr td a
    {
    color: Red;
    }
```

For

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="save" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

try

```
.gvwList tr td input[type="submit"]
            {
            color: Red;
            }
```